# Discovering peaks/patterns in time-series and clustering them

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, moving-window, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a dataset which contains minute level sensor measurements. Sample is shown here:
[image]

To me useful information are these peaks in time series, mostly their peak and duration. My idea is to take out only windows with each peak and then to cluster them to a few typical peaks. Problem is how to determine window size since they have different duration and they start at a different time each day.

I would like to get this, where each colour on the image is an array containing only the values and timestamp of that peak:

[image]

I am thinking of SAX, where I would need some methodology to cut the sequence when the value gets to low (normal), e.g. **abbbccdcbbbba**aaa**abbbbcbba**aaa, would be cut to **abbbccdcbbbba** and **abbbbcbba**. But maybe there is other, better way.

Any ideas and comments are welcome.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple approaches you might try.
They all exploit different kinds of patterns in your data, and they all have at least one parameter you'll need to tweak.

- Fixed-duration windows around a peak. As you've said, this doesn't work very well.
- Set a y-axis threshold. A peak starts when the value goes above this threshold, and ends when it goes below again. Some mild high-pass filtering may help here.
- Smooth your data (for example using a low-pass filter). Peaks start and end at the troughs, where the slope of the filtered data goes from negative to positive. Results depend on amount of smoothing.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these methods and come back if needed

Comment: I didn't get satisfying results with the filtering method, is there some possibility to use machine learning method for this?